# Compare columns from different excel files and add a column at the beginning of each with the output

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I want to start this by saying that I'm not an Excel expert so I kindly need some help.

Let's assume that I have 3 excel files: `main.xlsx`, `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx`. In all of them I have a column named `Serial Numbers`. I have to:

- lookup for all *serial numbers* in `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx` and verify if they are in `main.xlsx`.

If a serial number is find:

- on the last column of `main.xlsx`, on the same row with the *serial number* that was find write `OK + name_of_the_file_in which_it_was_found`. Else, write `NOK`. At the same time, write in `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx` `ok` or `nok` on the last column if the *serial number* was found or not.

*Mention*: `serial number` can be on different columns on `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx`

#### Example:

**main.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b      abcd        c         <-- ok,2.xlsx
b      c      1234        d         <-- ok,1.xlsx
c      d      3456        e         <-- ok,1.xlsx
d      e      4567        f         <-- NOK
e      f                  g         <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

**1.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b      1234        c          <-- OK (because is find in main)
b      c      lala        d          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
c      d      3456        e          <-- OK (because find main)
d      e      jjjj        f          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
e      f                  g          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

**2.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b                  c          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
b      c      abcd        d          <-- OK (because find main)
c      d      4533        e          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
d      e      jjjj        f          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
e      f                  g          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

Now, I tried doing this in Python, but apparently I couldn't figure how to write to the status column (tried using `dataFrames`), on the same line where the `serial number` is find. Any help would be much appreciated. (or at least some guidance)

My problem it's not finding the duplicates, but rather keeping track of the rows (to write the status on the correct `serial number`) and writing to the excel at the specified column (`status` column).

**My try:**

```
import pandas as pd

get_main = pd.ExcelFile('main.xlsx')
get_1 = pd.ExcelFile('1.xlsx')
get_2 = pd.ExcelFile('2.xlsx')

sheet1_from_main = get_main.parse(0)
sheet1_from_1 = get_1.parse(0)
sheet1_from_2 = get_2.parse(0)


column_from_main = sheet1_from_main.iloc[:, 2].real
column_from_main_py = []
for x in column_from_main:
    column_from_main_py.append(x)


column_from_1 = sheet1_from_1.iloc[:, 2].real
column_from_1_py = []
for y in column_from_1:
    column_from_1_py.append(y)


column_from_2 = sheet1_from_2.iloc[:, 2].real
column_2_py = []
for z in column_from_2:
    column_2_py.append(z)
```

---

Suggested edit:

```
import pandas as pd

get_main = pd.read_excel('main.xls', sheetname=0)
get_1 = pd.read_excel('1.xls', sheetname=0)
get_2 = pd.read_excel('2.xls', sheetname=0)


column_from_main = get_main.ix[:, 'Serial No.'].real
column_from_main_py = column_from_main.tolist()


column_from_1 = get_1.ix[:, 'SERIAL NUMBER'].real
column_from_1_py = column_from_1.tolist()


column_from_2 = get_2.ix[:, 'S/N'].real
column_from_2_py = column_from_2.tolist()

# Tried to put example data at specific column

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('first.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_column('M:M', None, None)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you can skip using excelfile and parse by using `pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=0)`.

As far as you columns go, try accessing the columns by name, not by index. And instead of using a for loop to create a list, use the tolist method. So instead of `column_from_main = sheet1_from_main.iloc[:, 2].real` you could say:

```
column_from_main = get_main.ix[:, 'serial number'].real
column_from_main_py = column_from_main.tolist()
```

Do the same for your other files as well. This will remove any issues with the serial number column being indexed differently and will operate faster.

As to your comment about not being able to write to 'Status' properly, can you show your code that you tried? I'd be more than happy to help, but it's nice to see what you've done to this point.

For checking the values in main against the other two files you will want to iterate over the lists you created and check if each value in the main list is in either of the other lists. Within that loop you can then assign the value of status based on whether the serial number in main is present in one, none, or both:

```
get_main['status'] = ''
get_1['status'] = ''
get_2['status'] = ''
for num in column_from_main_py:
    if num not in column_from_1_py and not in column_from_2_py:
        get_main.loc[get_main['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'NOK'
    elif num in column_from_1_py and not in column_from_2_py:
        get_main.loc[get_main['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'OK,1.xlsx'
        get_1.loc[get_1['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'OK'
    elif num not in column_from_1_py and in column_from_2_py:
        get_main.loc[get_main['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'OK,2.xlsx'
        get_2.loc[get_2['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'OK'
```

The lines get_main.loc are where you are setting the OK or NOK value to the status column. essentially it finds the index where some condition is true and then lets you change the value of a specific column at that index. Once you have gone through the main list then you can look through the lists for 1 and 2 to find serial numbers that aren't in main. Similarly:

```
for num in column_from_1_py:
    if num not in column_from_main_py:
        get_1.loc[get_1['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'NOK'
for num in column_from_2_py:
    if num not in column_from_main_py:
        get_2.loc[get_2['serial number'] == num, 'status'] = 'NOK'
```

That will set you NOK values and you should be good to go ahead and export the dataframes to excel (or csv, hdf, sql, etc...) and that should do it.

There are lots of ways you can index and select data in pandas depending on what you want to do. I recommend reading the [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) page in the docs as it has been a great reference for me.

Comment: thanks, I've made the modifications so far. I'll edit my answer to show what I've tried ^^ However I get an error at what you proposed: `column_from_1_py = column_from_1.tolistt() AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tolistt'` Any ideas ?

Comment: Nvm, I just misspelled it ^^. Other ideas?

Comment: instead of putting the data into a column in an excel file do it in place in the dataframe, once you have everything updated then export it back with pd.to_excel(). I've got to head out for the night, but should be able to help out some more tomorrow if that isn't clear enough.

Comment: Well, there's no hurry. I'll try to workout what you suggested and also edit the main post if I come up with something. Have a good night

Comment: @Dex'ter The edits should help you out a bit. While Copy and Pastes answer may work I think this solution is slightly more elegant, but that's a matter of your taste

Comment: @Dex'ter I was closing out my notebook for this test and noticed something strange. A good deal of the cells in your main.xlsx file have a second empty line of text included. This results in the value of those cells being the serial number with '\n' at the end. This will prevent you from being able to properly search for your terms without amending these values. You could use a loop to go through your column_from_main_py list, find the entries ending in \n and remove those two characters, or make sure the way the xlsx files are generated prevents this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the input files provided in the question aren't the actual input files being used. After obtaining the real input files, the following information/script was constructed. The below will not work for the question as currently asked.

To use the following example you first install petl and openpyxl (for your xlsx files):

```
pip install openpyxl
pip install petl
```

Script:

```
import petl

main = petl.fromxlsx('main.xlsx')
one = petl.fromxlsx('1.xlsx', row_offset=1)
two = petl.fromxlsx('2.xlsx')

non_serial_rows = petl.select(main, lambda rec: rec['serial number'] is None)
serial_rows = petl.select(main, lambda rec: rec['serial number'] is not None)
main_join_one = petl.join(serial_rows, petl.cut(one,['serial number']), key='serial number')
main_join_one_file = petl.addfield(main_join_one, 'file', 'ok, 1.xlsx')
main_join_two = petl.join(serial_rows, petl.cut(two,['serial number']), key='serial number')
main_join_two_file = petl.addfield(main_join_two, 'file', 'ok, 2.xlsx')
stacked_joins = petl.stack(main_join_two_file, main_join_one_file)
nok_rows = petl.antijoin(serial_rows, petl.cut(stacked_joins, ['serial number']),  key='serial number')
nok_rows = petl.addfield(nok_rows, 'file', 'NOK')
output_main = petl.stack(stacked_joins, non_serial_rows, nok_rows)
main_final = output_main

def main_compare(table):
    non_serial_rows = petl.select(table, lambda rec: rec['serial number'] is None)
    serial_rows = petl.select(table, lambda rec: rec['serial number'] is not None)
    ok_rows = petl.join(serial_rows, petl.cut(main, ['serial number']), key='serial number')
    ok_rows = petl.addfield(ok_rows, 'file', 'OK')
    nok_rows = petl.antijoin(serial_rows, petl.cut(main, ['serial number']), key='serial number')
    nok_rows = petl.addfield(nok_rows, 'file', 'NOK')
    return petl.stack(ok_rows, nok_rows, non_serial_rows)

one_final = main_compare(one)
two_final = main_compare(two)

petl.toxlsx(main_final, 'mainNew.xlsx')
print petl.lookall(main_final)
petl.toxlsx(one_final, '1New.xlsx')
print petl.lookall(one_final)
petl.toxlsx(two_final, '2New.xlsx')
print petl.lookall(two_final)
```

Output (Text on console, and the actual modified xlsx files)

Comment: Thanks ^^ Unfortunately I get this: `petl.errors.FieldSelectionError: selection is not a field or valid field index: 'serial number'` when trying to `petl.toxlsx(main_final, 'mainNew.xlsx')`

Comment: One of your xlsx (main, 1, or 2) are not as displayed in your example then. There must be a space or a typo in the headers of one of the files for the column serial number

Comment: My test files that work are here: http://www.filedropper.com/testfiles_2 . In addition I'm using python 2.7

Comment: @Dex'ter I've modified the script slightly to accommodate for the change in format. There are significant differences that would have been code breaking

Comment: Wow, that's almost perfect. But there's a weird thing: in the new xlsx files there are more lines than initially. Why is that ? Basically, each outputed file should have the same number of rows, isn't it ?

Comment: @Dex'ter It's because you have duplicate serial number's. You did not mention that case in your example. How should you we handle that?

Comment: I don't get it. Why would duplicates increase the number of rows in a xlsx? Let's suppose that in main.xlsx I have on 3 different rows the same serial number. If it is find in 1.xlsx or 2.xlsx, in the mainNew there will be also three rows with ok, file.xlsx right?

Comment: @CopyandPaste I'm not sure but it seems that you insinuated that my answer would not succeed. If so could you explain your premise? If I'm missing something I'd be more than happy to address it.